# Reading XML with namespace using Apache Beam XmlIO

Tags: java, xml, namespaces, apache-beam

I am trying to read an XML file into an Apache Beam pipeline. Some elements have namespaces and the namespace declaration is declared at the root node. I am able to parse the xml outside of Apache Beam using the standard JAXB parser. However, when I use XmlIO.read() function with beam I get the following exception:

com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Undeclared namespace prefix "g".

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
 <channel>
  <item>
   <!-- Basic Product Information -->
   <g:id><![CDATA[SAMI9000NAVKIT]]></g:id>
   <title><![CDATA[Original Samsung Galaxy S i9000 Navigation Kit]]></title>
   <link><![CDATA[https://www.mobileciti.com.au/original-samsung-galaxy-s-i9000-navigation-kit]]></link>
   <description><![CDATA[<p>SAMSUNG Galaxy S (i9000) Navigation Kit - Consists of handset cradle, window shield mount and car charger.</p>]]></description>
   <g:product_category><![CDATA[Electronics > Communications > Telephony > Mobile Phone Accessories]]></g:product_category>
   <g:product_type><![CDATA[Accessories > Car Kits]]></g:product_type>
....
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Beam code:

```
                .from(<Full file path>)
                .withRootElement("rss")
                .withRecordElement("item").withRecordClass(Item.class));
```

XML without namespace works fine. Any pointers is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at XmlSource [code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/c4e0b4ac0777f37f5eb775a8a83c56f66b3baac3/sdks/java/io/xml/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/xml/XmlSource.java#L179), unfortunately, I don't think it supports XML namespaces by default if you only specify a root element.

Though, as a workaround you can try to do something like this:

```
.withRootElement("rss version=\"2.0\" xmlns:g=\"http://base.google.com/ns/1.0\"")
```

and probably it will work.

Comment: Thanks @alexey-romanenko. The above solution worked.